# Ruby - Lazily Evaluated Hash

Tags: ruby, hash, promise, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to create a lazily-evaluated hash in Ruby:

```
hash = {foo: -> {go_find_foo} }
```

I don't want callers to know that they might be getting a `proc` back instead of a value - ideally I want the Hash class to get on each get whether the value is a `proc`, execute it, set the value in the Hash to the return value of the lambda, and finally return the value to the client.

Ideally I'd like to be able to define these hashes using standard syntax, as in the code example above. This means that I can't really use extension, as then I'd need to invoke the constructor manually (`hash = LazyHash.new`). If I monkey-patch, then I can't delegate to the original implementation of `[]`.

Any ideas? Are there any libraries that already do this? Is there any way to tell Ruby which implementation of `Hash` to instantiate when interpreting the `{}` symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GFD - not sure how I missed this: http://promise.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 4):

You can store the original implementation of `[]` using `alias_method`, and then reference it in your overridden method.

Here's a working implementation using monkey patching.

```
class Hash
  alias_method :old_brackets, :[]

  def [](member)
    value = old_brackets(member) # Delegate to old implementation
    self[member] = value.call if value.respond_to?(:call)
    value
  end
end
```

This has the obvious downside of eliminating the possibility of having a `Hash` map with `Proc` or `lambda` values anywhere in your code base, *possibly breaking Rails*. Consider using something like [refinements](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/11/30/ruby-2-0-refinements-in-practice/) to narrow the scope of your monkey patch.

Comment: Not a good idea to do that within a Hash as this pretty certainly will break some rails methods. Probably much safer way is to create a subclass of Hash (then you can do without aliasing and calling super instead).

Comment: @BroiSatse: You are definitely correct. The poster explicitly said he wanted to keep the hash literal, though. I'm not saying this is a good idea. I'm generally averse to monkey patching. Not sure if it's possible to make this play with Rails, maybe using refinements, but this is essentially what he's asking for. I'll add a not about potential issues with Rails. Thanks!

Comment: I pretty much like monkey patching, however only for extending given class, not modifying it. In this case we could add a method `dynamic` or sth which would return our dynamic version of hash?

Answer (score 0):

The `Hash` constructor could accept a block, to calculate the response. You could use that for your problem:

```
hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = "Go Fish: #{key}" }
```

So you could create a new class which inherits `Hash` and you could do the following:

```
class CalculatedHash < Hash
  def initialize(rules)
    super() do |hash, key|
      hash[key] = rules.fetch(key).call
    end
  end
end
```

And then:

```
hash = CalculatedHash.new(foo: -> { go_find_foo })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [hash block constructor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new):

```
def go_find(key)
  "shiny #{key} value"
end

h = Hash.new do |hash, key|
  hash[key] = go_find(key) if [:foo, :bar, :baz].include? key
end

h[:foo] # => "shiny foo value"
h[:quz] # => nil
```

Now the values will be evaluated the first time you search for the key.

However, note that the keys will not appear in the hash until you search for them (as they are also added lazily).